# Meaning (and Source) of the names of the Imahos

Tags: names

What is the meaning (and source) of the names of the Imahos - Sarah, Rivkah, Rachel, and Leah?

Comment: Rashi on Bereisheet 11:29 https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.29?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en might be a start

Comment: Isn't it in the name "imahos" the mother's similar to "avos" in regards to avrohom, yitzchok, and yakov

Comment: Rachel is a ewe. (Is it an ewe or a ewe? )

Comment: OP, are you specifically looking for classical Jewish sources on the matter or would general scholarship be enough?

Comment: Anything helps.